# ¿Cómo evitar datos duplicados en un dataGridView en C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Estoy intentando agregar datos en un `datagrid` usando `DataTable` mediante una condición. Si el ID que traigo de un `dataRow` es diferente al ID que tengo en la celda de mi `datagrid`, agregar el dato nuevo en el `datagrid` si no solo actualizar algunos datos del `datagrid`.

Sí me agrega los datos, el problema es que mis datos se duplican. No sé si tengo algún error de lógica o de código. Pensé en utilizar un `break` en mi condición y un `row.delete` pero no funcionó.

```
 DataTable dt = _datos.llenaDataDatos(cadena,cbxDatabase.Text);
                if (dataStatus.Rows.Count-1 > 0)//si es mayor a 0 agrego por primera vez las filas
                {

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)//recorrido del datatable
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataStatus.Rows.Count; i++)//recorro las filas de datagrid
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) != Convert.ToInt32(row["pid"]))
                            {
                                dataStatus.Rows.Add("", "", row["pid"], row["usename"], row["application_name"], row["datname"], row["client_addr"], row.IsNull("backend_start") ? row["backend_start"] : "", row["state"], row.IsNull("query_start") ? row["query_start"] : "", row.IsNull("xact_start") ? row["xact_start"] : "", row["wait_event"], row["query"]);

                            }                            
                            else
                            {
                                dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = row["state"];
                                dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = row["query_start"];
                                dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = row["wait_event"];

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                            dataStatus.Rows.Add("", "", row["pid"], row["usename"], row["application_name"], row["datname"], row["client_addr"], row.IsNull("backend_start") ? row["backend_start"] : "", row["state"], row.IsNull("query_start") ? row["query_start"] : "", row.IsNull("xact_start") ? row["xact_start"] : "", row["wait_event"], row["query"]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yo intentaria obtener todos los datos que contiene el datagrid, guardarlo en un arreglo y despues comparar el dato que se va agregar con el arreglo y ver si coincide con los datos del arreglo, si el nuevo dato se encuentra en el arreglo, no se añade al datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es solo un problema de lógica.

si vos haces esto:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)//recorrido del datatable
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataStatus.Rows.Count; i++)//recorro las filas de datagrid
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Estas comprobando cada fila de la grilla, con cada fila de tus datos nuevos... y que pasa?

que al hacer esa comparacion, por cada fila de tus datos nuevos, o agregas o editas una fila.. pero por cada fila! y entonces no solo duplicas, si no que metes muchisimos datos de mas...

Lo que hay que hacer es otra cosa.. tu algoritmo tiene que comparar todos contra todos, pero ante cada iteración completa de comparación, no guardar directamente, si no despues, cuando sabe que tiene que hacer.

Para que se entienda, deberia ser algo asi:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)//recorrido del datatable
{
    int pos = 0;
    boolean esigual = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataStatus.Rows.Count; i++)//recorro las filas de datagrid
    {
        // Comparo
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(row["pid"]))
        {
            esigual = true; // solo ocurre si es un id repetido
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    //ahora ya compare todas las filas, si hago lo que hacias antes adentro
    if (!esigual)
    {
        dataStatus.Rows.Add("", "", row["pid"], row["usename"], row["application_name"], row["datname"], row["client_addr"], row.IsNull("backend_start") ? row["backend_start"] : "", row["state"], row.IsNull("query_start") ? row["query_start"] : "", row.IsNull("xact_start") ? row["xact_start"] : "", row["wait_event"], row["query"]);
    }                          
    else
    {
        dataStatus.Rows[pos].Cells[8].Value = row["state"];
        dataStatus.Rows[pos].Cells[9].Value = row["query_start"];
        dataStatus.Rows[pos].Cells[11].Value = row["wait_event"];
    }
}
```

Comment: fue muy útil tu respuesta..

Comment: @mica si te sirvio recuerda aceptarla. Si no sirvio, dime que falla asi la arreglamos, o escribe tu propia respuesta con lo que hiciste para que funcionara.

Comment: Solo agrege otro for en el else donde actualizo las filas y listo..                                                                    else
                        {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataStatus.Rows.Count; i++)//
                        {
                            dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = row["state"];
                            dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = row["query_start"];
                            dataStatus.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = row["wait_event"];
                        }
                        }

Comment: No entiendo porque agregaste ese for.. si ya el que estaba deberia haber solucionado todo. Queres explicar eso en una respuesta

Comment: lo agrege porque el for del primer recorrido termina donde se hace la comparacion de que si son iguales, al momento de hacer la comparacion de que si es diferente entra en otra sentencia donde el contenido del for pierde accesibilidad, y al momento de actualizar mis datos la variable i marca como no error, es por ello que tuve que volver a gregar.

Comment: Ahhh ya entendi tu problema... no.. tenemos que evitar eso.. deja que revisamos la respuesta...

Comment: Listo.. fijate si con la edicion (agregue una variable pos, y la use para grabar en la fila que encontramos) no se soluciona tu problema...